# Displaying folder tabs in sublime

Tags: editor, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I find myself in a situation, where I need to open 4+ project folders and edit various files on all of them back and forth. I find it a tad bit annoying, when I have minimized them and hovering on taskbar shows me 4 of them and I keep mixing them up, which I want to edit.

Is there a plugin or way or a different editor all together, that will display my opened folders in sublime, just like it basically shows opened files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about sublime ( but in eclipse/aptana or intellij/phpstorm, I do switches on projects).  Because the way sublime works, it shows you by default one project folder per one sublime running. You can try this:

Open your 1st folder with sublime.  Drag the 2nd folder onto sublime's sidebar. Do the rest of the folders same way.

For taskbar issue, you can try Taskbar properties>'Never combine' and just Alt Tabbing/Alt+shift Tabbing them...